# change setting delay audio while stream video by ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have 2 rtmp, one of them for audio playback and one for streaming video. I mix all of them  using ffmpeg, but I want to change the delay between audio and video while running ffmpeg. How can I do that?

Comment: You want to set a delay at the beginning? Or change delay on demand while streaming?

Comment: @llogan, I want to change the delay while streaming. Since the delay changes over time, sometimes the video will play faster than the audio and vice versa